# Как при свайпе на мобильных устройтсвах скрыть меню на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть функция:

```
$('.btn-bars').click(function(){
    $('.menu').slideToggle();
});
```

Меню открывается на половину экрана. Когда пользователь будет свайпить вниз в другой половине экрана, надо закрыть slideToggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('SELECTOR').on('scroll', function(event) { - создаем обработчик скролла
  $('.menu').hide(); - скрываем меню
})
```

Так же желательно реализовать инициализацию обработчика при открытии меню и  удаление обработчика при скрытиию

Comment: Привет, спасибо твой метод помог. но я решил иначе сделать (внизу ответ)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var the_top = $(document).scrollTop();
       if (the_top > 100) {
       $('.menu').slideUp();
    }
});
```